# Is there any other solution in Excelpackage in C# (Using OfficeOpenXml in EPPlus.dll)

Tags: c#, epplus, excelpackage

i used EPPlus.dll as my library in creating Excel sheets.
But using these codes, i got an error: `Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in ExcelReports.cs:line 37`

```
            28. String filename = "D:\\" + MonthYear + "_journal.xls";
            29. FileInfo template = new FileInfo("D:\\template_journal.xls");
            30. if (File.Exists(filename))
            31. {
            32.    File.Delete(filename); 
            33. }
            34. FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(filename);
            35. ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile, template);
            36. ExcelWorksheet journalsheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Journal"];
            37. journalsheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Sample Value";
            38. pck.Save();
```

Comment: Either `journalsheet` is null or `Cells["C1"]` is null.  Check those values.

Comment: the real cause of theproblem is in line 36.
the ExcelPackage cannot recognized "Journal" as worksheet.
so i used the array number [0] instead of ["Journal"].
it solveds my problem